# Incoherent local/global line numbering in Scinotes

Tags: user-interface, scilab

When I switch on the "local line numbering" option in SciNotes, I get a strange effect. The line numbers show as local (starting with the "function" line) for some of my functions, but global (counting from the beginning of the code file) for others.

My first thought was that a function wasn't ended properly (too few "end" instructions wrt the number of opened loops, ifs and other such), but then my code would crash, which it doesn't. Also, indentation looks fine when I auto-adjust it.

It doesn't very much get in my way, but I wonder if it isn't a symptom of something more serious cooking under the surface. Has anybody had a similar experience?

FWIW I'm using Scilab 6.0.2 under Windows 10.

Comment: Are you using `end` or `endfunction` as keyword to end your functions ? Can you try to open your code in Scilab 6.1 ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried changing endfunction to end; it doesn't seem to affect the line numbering. But I think I have the answer, and I will put it in an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the source of the "problem". Line numbering only gets local in a function whose first line (the one with the "function" keyword) is ***not*** terminated with a semicolon.

Like this:

```
1   // This is my fantastic power program
2   clear;
3   clc;
4   cd "c:\myDir\Scilab\Sandbox\FunAndGames"
5
6   function S=square(x);  // <-- now you see it
7       S=x*x;             //   (the semicolon, I mean)
8   endfunction;
9
1   function C=cube(x)     // <-- now you don't
2       C=x*x*x;
3   endfunction;
13
14
15  // Now the body of my program:
16
17  X=zeros(5,5);
18  ....
```